# Boolean Parameter in procedure to hide toolbar not working

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the procedure below to hide the toolbar. All others work when set to FALSE, but the bold line below does not work. The toolbar still shows even when set to FALSE.

```
Sub engageDashboard(state As Boolean)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = state

   **Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"", state)"**
   Application.DisplayFormulaBar = state

   ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = state
   ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = state
   ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = state

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the exact line you're trying to execute:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"", state)"
```

then the `state` variable is not passed into the string. In that case, you need to use the following:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"", " & state & ")"
```

This will use the current value of `state` and concatenate it into the call properly.